# Не понимаю почему m принимается за булеан (String cannot be converted to boolean if (m = "man") )

Tags: java, строки

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        String m;
        int[] a;
        Scanner wm = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("man or woman?");
        m = wm.nextLine();
        if (m = "man"){
          i++;
          a[0]=i;
        } else {
          System.out.println("You fit!");
        }
  
  }
```

Comment: if (m == "man"). Один знак "=" - присваивает, два знака "=" - сравнивает

Comment: Потому что вы не сравниваете строки, а присваиваете значение переменной if (m = "man"). Правильно if (m = ="man")

Comment: Не принимается за, а пытается привестись к

Answer (score 1):

Как уже написали, `m = "man"` это выражение:

1. которое присваивает переменной `m` значение выражения справа от знака присваивания
2. результатом которого, является значение выражения справа от знака присваивания

Строка не может быть использована в `if` и в java нет неявного приведения к `boolean`, поэтому и получаете ошибку.

Правильно сравнение делать используя метод `equals`. Удобней всего так `Objects.equals(m, "man")`. Можно так `"man".equals(m)`. Если точно известно, что `m != null`, то можно `m.equals("man")`.

Обратите внимание, что использовать `==` для сравнения содержимого строк - нельзя, т.к. такое сравнение в общем случае не работает, т.к. сравнивает ссылки на объекты, а не их содержимое.

Comment: Cпасибо, разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

сделайте так указал  @kompaniietst

```
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i=0;
    String m;
    int a;
    Scanner wm = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("man or woman?");
    m = wm.nextLine();

    if (m == "man"){
      i++;
      a = i;
    } else {
      System.out.println("You fit!");
    }
  }
```

не много подкорректировал чтоб работало